# How can I make the height of a video constrained to the height of its grid cell?

Tags: html, css, video, css-grid

I have a page with a grid layout having two boxes stacked vertically on the left and a main content box on the right.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.videos {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="videos">
    <div>Box 1</div>
    <div>Box 2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    This is the content
  </div>
</div>
```

So far so good. Now, I want to put videos into the two boxes on the left, so that the height of each video will be fixed to half of the page height, and the width will scale based on the aspect ratio of the videos.

The videos should grow and shrink according to the height of the page.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.videos {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.videos div {
  height: 100%;
}

video {
  height: 100%;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="videos">
    <div>
      <video controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div>
      <video controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    This is the content
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work as expected. The page is expanding according to the size of the videos and causing a vertical scroll bar. The height of the videos is not constrained to the height of their grid cell.

How can I make the height of a video constrained to the height of its grid cell?

Comment: just add below css and check it:

video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

Comment: @AjayChauhan Doesn't seem to work

Comment: Perhaps get rid of all those percentage lengths? https://jsfiddle.net/2b396uL1/

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin But I want `.container` to occupy 100% of its parent's height (in this case the page). Also the video should shrink when the page height is too short.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it, with flexbox. I'm not entirely sure why the `videos` box is stuck at half the width of the viewport, despite my desire for it to collapse to the content. Perhaps someone smarter than I will edit this answer to achieve the desired result.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.container>div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.videos {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex: 0 1 min-content;
}

.container .videos div {
  max-width: min-content;
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

video {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="videos">
    <div>
      <video controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div>
      <video controls>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    This is the content
  </div>
</div>
```